# Почему SVG никак не реагирует?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation

Хочу плавно отрисовать эту руку с калькулятором, нашел часть руки, её длину, но почему она никак не реагирует на изменений stroke-daharray и offset, причем любая часть свг так же 0 реакции дает, в чем ошибаюсь ?

```css
.hand-calc-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 547px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 547px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 842 595" style="enable-background:new 0 0 842 595;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .st1 {
        opacity: 0.5;
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 3;
        stroke-miterlimit: 22.9256;
        enable-background: new;
    }
    </style>
    <g id="path">
        <g class="st0">
          <path d="M628.8,322.8C628.8,322.8,628.8,323,628.8,322.8L628.8,322.8z" />
          <path class="hand-calc-1" d="M650.7,438.3c-20.9,13.5-37.4,24.1-49.8,40.8c-8.6,11.4-48.9,53.9-80.2,86.8c-14.5,15.4-27.1,28.6-33.7,35.8
    c-0.5,0.6-0.5,1.5,0.2,2.2c0.6,0.5,1.5,0.5,2-0.1c6.3-6.9,19-20.2,33.7-35.7c31.4-33,71.8-75.6,80.4-87.1
    c12.1-16.3,28.4-26.8,49-40.1c9.8-6.4,20.6-13.3,32.5-21.9c-1.7,0-3.4,0-5.2,0C669.1,426.4,659.5,432.6,650.7,438.3z" />
          <path class="hand-calc-2" d="M752.1,304.5c-0.4-3.1-1.7-5.7-3.7-7.7s-4.6-3.3-7.7-3.9c-3.3-0.6-7-0.4-11.1,0.9c1.2-1.2,2.5-2.4,3.8-3.5
    c10.8-9.7,20.1-18,5.3-39.3c-4.9-7-11.1-9-16.7-7.8c-3,0.7-5.8,2.2-8.1,4.3c-2.3,2.1-4,4.8-5,7.8c-1.8,5.7-0.7,12.4,5.5,17.9v2.7
    h-9.9c-0.4,0-0.8,0.2-1.1,0.5c-0.5,0.6-1.4,1.6-2.5,2.8c-3.7,4.1-10,11.1-15.4,15.7c-3.4,2.9-5.5,4.2-6.7,4.4
    c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4c0.4-1.9,2.4-5,5.1-7.6l14-13.4c0.5-0.5,0.5-1.4,0-2c-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4-1-0.4h-44.9c3.2-2.9,6.3-5.8,9.5-8.8
    c19.2-18,31.8-38.3,60-40.5v13c0.1,0.8,0.7,1.4,1.5,1.4c2.6,0,5.1,0,7.3,0.6c2.1,0.6,4,1.8,5.6,4.1c0.4,0.6,1.3,0.8,1.9,0.4
    c10.5-6.2,15.5-12.5,16.6-17.9c0.6-2.7,0.1-5.2-1.1-7.4c-1.2-2.1-3.2-3.8-5.7-5.1c-5.7-2.9-14.3-3.3-23.7,0V102.7
    c0-0.8-0.6-1.4-1.4-1.4H608.8c-0.8,0-1.4,0.6-1.4,1.4v115.1c-3.9,0.8-7.5,6.7-12.8,15.1c-4.5,7.1-10.1,16-17.8,25.4
    c-31.7,38.4-31.8,42-32.7,67.8c-0.3,7.2-0.6,16.1-1.7,28c-0.2,2.8-0.6,5.7-0.9,8.5c-0.6,5.3-1.2,10-1.2,14.3s0.5,8.1,2,11.2
    c-4.5,3.5-9.8,10.1-15.6,20.8c-2.5,4.5-4.9,8.5-9.4,14.3c-4.6,5.9-11.3,13.5-22.4,25.3c-59.4,62.9-121.5,102.3-193.3,148l-7.7,4.9
    c-0.6,0.5-0.8,1.3-0.4,2c0.5,0.6,1.3,0.8,2,0.4l7.7-4.9c72-45.8,134.1-85.3,193.8-148.5c11.2-11.9,18-19.6,22.6-25.5
    c4.6-6,7.1-10.1,9.6-14.7c5.6-10.1,10.5-16.5,14.6-19.7c2.4,3.3,6.3,5.7,12.4,7.1c0.9,6.2,0.4,14.6-2,24c0,0.2-0.1,0.5,0,0.7
    c0,0,4.2,8.4,11.1,17.2c3.5,4.4,7.6,8.9,12.2,12.7c10.3,8.4,15.5,9.4,18.1,6.2c2.4-2.9,2-9.3,1.5-16.8c-0.2-2.6-0.3-5.3-0.4-7.9
    c-0.5-18.9,1.5-19.1,27.5-20.8c0.7-0.1,1.5-0.1,2.3-0.2c-1.4-1-2.7-2.2-4.4-2.6c-26.6,1.8-28.8,2.5-28.3,23.6
    c0.1,2.8,0.2,5.5,0.4,8c0.4,6.9,0.8,12.8-0.9,14.9c-1.5,1.9-5.4,0.5-14.1-6.6c-4.4-3.7-8.4-8.1-11.7-12.3
    c-6-7.6-9.8-14.6-10.5-15.9c2.2-9,2.9-17.3,2.1-23.6c3.6,0.6,8,0.9,13.3,0.9c8.6,0,15.9-1.3,22.1-3.6c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.2
    c-1-0.6-2-1.3-2.9-2.2c-5.7,2-12.3,3.1-20,3.1c-5.5,0-9.9-0.4-13.6-1.1c-0.3-1.2-0.6-2.4-1-3.4c-1.1-2.9-2.7-5-4.7-6
    c-2.1-1.1-4.6-1.1-7.4,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-1.3-2.6-1.7-5.8-1.7-9.5c0-4,0.5-8.7,1.1-13.9c0.3-2.6,0.6-5.4,0.9-8.5
    c1.1-12,1.4-20.9,1.7-28.1c0.9-24.9,1-28.5,32-66.1c7.8-9.5,13.5-18.6,18-25.7c4.6-7.4,7.9-12.6,10.4-13.7v41.7
    c-1.7,3.9-3.4,7.7-5.1,11.4c-2.3,5.3-4.5,10.2-6.3,14.6c-3.8,9.5-4.7,14.9-1.9,17.2c2.8,2.2,8.6,1,18.6-2.7
    c12.5-4.7,24.4-14,36.5-25h44.7l-11.4,11c-3.1,3-5.3,6.6-5.9,8.9c-0.2,1.1-0.2,2,0.2,2.7c0.5,0.9,1.4,1.4,2.7,1.2
    c1.7-0.2,4.3-1.7,8.3-5c5.6-4.7,12-11.9,15.7-16c0.9-0.9,1.6-1.7,2.1-2.3h10.7c0.8,0,1.4-0.6,1.4-1.4v-4.8c0-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.5-1.1
    c-5.6-4.7-6.6-10.5-5.1-15.3c0.8-2.5,2.3-4.8,4.2-6.6c1.9-1.8,4.2-3.1,6.7-3.6c4.5-0.9,9.7,0.8,13.8,6.7
    c13.3,19.3,4.9,26.9-4.9,35.6c-2.9,2.6-5.9,5.3-8.6,8.4c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c-0.7,0.4-1.3,0.8-2,1.2c-3.6,2.3-8,4.3-12.4,6.3
    c-5.7,2.7-11.6,5.3-16.3,8.9c-7.8,5.8-11.6,11.5-12.4,16.2c-0.5,2.6,0,4.9,1.1,6.9c1.1,1.9,2.9,3.5,5.3,4.5
    c4.8,2.1,11.9,2.2,20-0.8c8.7-3.2,19.3-8,27.4-13.7c4.7-3.3,8.5-6.8,10.7-10.5c2.3-3.9,2.8-8,0.6-12c-0.8-1.4-1.9-2.8-3.5-4.2
    c-2.9-2.6-6.2-3.4-9.5-3.6c3.1-0.7,5.8-0.9,8.2-0.4c2.5,0.4,4.6,1.5,6.2,3.1c1.6,1.6,2.6,3.6,3,6.1c0.5,4-0.5,8.9-3.7,14.3
    c1.4-1,3-2,4.6-2.7C752.1,311.9,752.6,307.9,752.1,304.5z M546.6,388.7c1.9-0.9,3.6-1,4.9-0.3c1.4,0.7,2.6,2.2,3.4,4.4
    c0.2,0.5,0.4,1,0.6,1.7c-4.4-1.3-7.3-3.1-9.2-5.6C546.4,388.8,546.5,388.8,546.6,388.7z M611.6,300.3c-9,3.4-14.1,4.6-15.8,3.2
    c-1.6-1.4-0.6-5.8,2.7-14c1.7-4.1,3.9-9.1,6.3-14.4c0.8-1.9,1.7-3.7,2.5-5.6v7.3c0,0.8,0.6,1.4,1.4,1.4h35.9
    C633.7,287.9,622.8,296.1,611.6,300.3z M647.8,275.4H610v-12.3V218V104.1h111v113.2c0,0.8,0.6,1.4,1.4,1.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.2
    c9.3-3.7,17.8-3.5,23.2-0.8c2,1,3.6,2.4,4.5,4c0.9,1.6,1.2,3.5,0.8,5.5c-0.9,4.5-5.2,9.9-14.2,15.4c-1.8-2.3-3.9-3.5-6.3-4.2
    c-2.1-0.6-4.4-0.7-6.7-0.7v-13.3c0-0.8-0.6-1.4-1.4-1.4c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.4,0c-33.7,3.3-43.1,22.8-63,41.5
    C655.6,268.2,651.7,271.9,647.8,275.4z M678.8,299.4C678.9,299.5,678.8,299.5,678.8,299.4L678.8,299.4z M739.6,301.5
    c1.3,1.2,2.3,2.3,2.9,3.5c1.6,3,1.2,6.1-0.6,9.2c-2,3.4-5.5,6.6-9.9,9.7c-7.9,5.5-18.3,10.3-26.8,13.4c-7.4,2.7-13.7,2.7-17.9,0.9
    c-1.8-0.8-3.2-2-4-3.4c-0.8-1.4-1.1-3.1-0.8-5c0.7-4.1,4.2-9.1,11.3-14.4c4.5-3.4,10.2-6,15.8-8.6c4.5-2,8.9-4.1,12.7-6.5
    c0.8-0.5,1.6-1,2.5-1.6c0.5-0.1,1.1-0.1,1.6-0.1C731.1,298.5,736,298.3,739.6,301.5z" />
  <path d="M678.8,299.4C678.8,299.5,678.9,299.5,678.8,299.4L678.8,299.4z" />
    </g>
        <rect x="621.8" y="115.8" class="st1" width="87.5" height="36" />
        <rect x="621.2" y="165.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <rect x="686.6" y="165.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <rect x="653.9" y="165.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <rect x="621.2" y="197.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <rect x="686.6" y="197.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <rect x="653.9" y="197.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <rect x="621.2" y="231.8" class="st1" width="22.7" height="22.7" />
        <polygon class="st1" points="663.2,254.5 653.9,254.5 653.9,231.8 676.5,231.8 676.5,240.6  " />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Немного не понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать, если вы используете `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset` из стиля `check`, так как только там они есть. Не нашел упоминания стиля для `id` `check` внутри вашего кода `svg`. Или я не сильно хорошо понял вашу проблему.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin виноват, для .hand-calc-1 стили прописаны

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Анимация рисования линии возможна только при выполнении условия, что
  патч не имеет разрывов. В вашем случае контуры руки и пальцев
  нарисованы двойными линиями, высока вероятность, что где-то есть
  разрыв целой линии, наиболее вероятно, что это произошло в точках
  пересечения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
 - `.hand-calc-1 {   stroke-dasharray: 547px;

 stroke-dashoffset: 547px;
   }`

Расчёт через метод JS `getTotalLength()` выдает длину патча - `3788px`, а не `547px`

### Вывод

При существующей векторной фигуре анимация при помощи `stroke-dashoffset` невозможна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, анимация в принципе не возможна, я даже разные части не смогу по порядку анимировать ? Нужно перерисовать вектор одним path ?

Comment: @YourDeveloper Да нужно всё перерисовывать и плюс квадраты кнопок калькулятора перерисовать, так как `rect` не анимируется, нужно их патчами нарисовать. На вашем месте, я бы плюс поставил за потраченное время на анализ и за полезную информацию

Comment: спасибо за информацию, не люблю преждевременно ставить, потом люди пропадают :( А так конечно, вы отчасти решили мою проблему, благодарю.

Comment: @YourDeveloper Благодарю. Пробуйте ещё раз нарисовать, но одинарными линиями, не двойными. Сделаете, если не будет получаться анимация, обязательно помогу, если что подправлю патчи

Comment: @YourDeveloper как дела с новым патчем или не хочется переделывать? :))

Comment: если честно это не мой патч был, я только пытался работать с ним, увы сам не знаю как подобное рисуют, если подскажите буду благодарен)

Comment: @YourDeveloper Рисуют в векторном редакторе Пройдитесь по ответам с тегом Inkscape там много раз с картинками отвечал  вот буквально вчера https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790157/28748