# способ верстки волнистого фона. сложный фон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, inkscape

Пытаюсь представить способы и пути решения верстки подобного шаблона:

[image: картинка шаблона верстки]

Подскажите, где почитать, как сделать такой фон не целой картинкой. Интересно и отдельные белые частицы и наклонные волнистые линии.

Comment: Это  ответ на твой вопрос  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784137/Подскажите-какой-нибудь-хороший-материал-по-изучению-svg/784166#784166

Comment: Спасибо!Говорят что поддержка браузерами еще не идеальная, но изучать уже стоит!

Comment: Не правильно говорят.....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Один из возможных вариантов решения

Как я понял,  нужно, чтобы и фон был, как на картинке, плюс и адаптивным был, и была бы возможность совместить его с вёрсткой меню, иконок-ссылок и т.д

Идеальный вариант,- это иметь хорошего, знающего дизайнера, который  понимает технику вёрстки и предоставил бы вам векторный фон, без надписей, картинок иконок, текста.
 И плюс к этому картинку конечного результата.
*Но имеем, что имеем и учимся работать с дизайнером, то есть требовать от него, что написано выше.*

Придется делать работу за дизайнера.
Изогнутые линии будем рисовать  в векторном редакторе.

*Последовательность действий:*

- Открываем вашу картинку в векторном редакторе
- С помощью инструмента

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]  наносим узловые точки на кривые линии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Выделяем узловые точки  -   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- и делаем их автоматически закругленными -- [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- С помощью рычагов узловых точек, подгоняем нашу кривую к существующей
  на картинке
- Сохраняем файл в формате *.svg
- Забираем патчи кривых из файла
- Добавляем цвет в криволинейные области
- Вместо круглой картинки слайдера добавляем окружность, для того чтобы
  вы в дальнейшем могли добавить на это место рабочий слайдер поверх
  фона

`<circle cx="435" cy="185" r="120" fill="#D7D7D5" />`

Ниже полный код векторного, адаптивного фона:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 655 364" id="svg2" version="1">
 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFxHW.png" width="100%" height="100%" id="image4"/>
  <g stroke="none">
  <path d="m428 2c0 0 68 35 104 46 23 7 48 7 71 13 17 5 50 19 50 19l2 284-91-1c0 0-4-37-10-55-6-16-13-33-25-46C499 233 452 228 421 201 390 175 371 140 347 106 335 88 327 72 312 50 299 31 262 2 262 2Z" id="path3342" style="fill:#37417e;"/>
  <path d="M0 265 0 364l164 0c0 0-9-3-13-5-13-7-23-16-35-25-6-5-12-10-19-14-9-5-20-8-30-13-7-3-13-8-19-12-4-2-8-4-11-6-3-2-7-4-10-6-4-3-6-6-10-9-3-2-5-5-9-7-2-1-7-3-7-3z" id="path3360" style="fill:#37417e;"/>
  <path d="M0 279 0 364 70 363c0 0-6-3-9-6-2-2-3-6-4-9-1-4-2-8-4-12-2-3-4-6-7-9-3-3-7-6-9-9-2-3-4-7-6-10-2-3-4-6-7-9-3-3-6-5-9-8-4-3-7-6-11-9-2-1-4-5-4-5z" id="path3362" style="fill:#E53063;"/>
  <path d="m430 2 224-1 0 0-1 79c0 0-30-1-45-5-16-6-32-13-48-18-20-5-36-3-68-15C469 34 430 2 430 2Z" id="path3364" style="fill:#E53063;"/>
  </g>
 <circle cx="435" cy="185" r="120" fill="#D7D7D5" />
  </svg>
```

### Вёрстка

Сейчас у нас одновременно совмещены векторный фон, плюс картинка из вопроса автора.
 *Я конечно не буду делать полную вёрстку, лишь начну её.*

Автор вопроса сделает вёрстку, как ему нравится. Сейчас надо просто определиться, как связать векторный фон с остальными элементами.

Так как фон занимает всё пространство, то `html` элементы будут выше на слой `z-index:1;` и абсолютно спозиционированы, чтобы попасть в нужное место.
 Блок, с `svg` кодом будет - `position:relative;` блок с `html` - `position:absolute;`

В примере верстки добавляются лишь два слова `Интересный Ресторан`

Зеленая рамка показывает границы блока `html`.

Когда закончите вёрстку уберите из `svg` блока строчку добавляющую `png` фон.

```
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFxHW.png" width="100%" height="100%" id="image4"/>
```

```css
.container{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.menuSite {
width:30%;
height:60%;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 top:20%;
  left:16%;
  padding-left:1em;
  padding-top:-1.5em;
  outline:1px solid green;
} 
.p1{
 font-size:2em;
 color:#B1CFDC;  
}
.p2{
 font-size:1.3em;
 color:#D5B2C2;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuSite">
<p class="p1"> Интересный  </p> 
<p class="p2">РЕСТОРАН </p>
  </div>
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 655 364" id="svg2" version="1">
 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFxHW.png" width="100%" height="100%" id="image4"/> 
  <g stroke="none">
  <path d="m428 2c0 0 68 35 104 46 23 7 48 7 71 13 17 5 50 19 50 19l2 284-91-1c0 0-4-37-10-55-6-16-13-33-25-46C499 233 452 228 421 201 390 175 371 140 347 106 335 88 327 72 312 50 299 31 262 2 262 2Z" id="path3342" style="fill:#37417e;"/>
  <path d="M0 265 0 364l164 0c0 0-9-3-13-5-13-7-23-16-35-25-6-5-12-10-19-14-9-5-20-8-30-13-7-3-13-8-19-12-4-2-8-4-11-6-3-2-7-4-10-6-4-3-6-6-10-9-3-2-5-5-9-7-2-1-7-3-7-3z" id="path3360" style="fill:#37417e;"/>
  <path d="M0 279 0 364 70 363c0 0-6-3-9-6-2-2-3-6-4-9-1-4-2-8-4-12-2-3-4-6-7-9-3-3-7-6-9-9-2-3-4-7-6-10-2-3-4-6-7-9-3-3-6-5-9-8-4-3-7-6-11-9-2-1-4-5-4-5z" id="path3362" style="fill:#E53063;"/>
  <path d="m430 2 224-1 0 0-1 79c0 0-30-1-45-5-16-6-32-13-48-18-20-5-36-3-68-15C469 34 430 2 430 2Z" id="path3364" style="fill:#E53063;"/>
  </g>
 <circle cx="435" cy="185" r="120" fill="#D7D7D5" />
  </svg>
</div>
```